# R Condition Function/Loop to check value in Data Frame

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I am trying to write code that checks to see if the 1 value in a df  is greater than another value in a different row/column in the same df.

I have the following as a sample:

```
Date GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close
2014-02-28 2014-02-28   1855.12   1867.92  1847.67    1859.45
2014-02-27 2014-02-27   1844.90   1854.53  1841.13    1854.29
2014-02-26 2014-02-26   1845.79   1852.65  1840.66    1845.16
2014-02-25 2014-02-25   1847.66   1852.91  1840.19    1845.12
```

I want to create a loop or function that checks to see if GSPC.Open is greater than or equal to the previous day's GSPC.Close. I would imagine the code would look like

```
if (df$GSPC.Open >= df$GSPC.Close[1]) {
    df$GSPC.AboveOpen = 1
}
```

but I keep an length > 1 error.

I would like the function to create an column df$GSPC.AboveOpen filled w/ discrete values if the current day's open is greater than or equal to the previous day's close.

How do I write this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advise to use a loop here. You are using a time series - therefore, use appropriate time series methods (such as `lag`).

This code compares the current day's open with previous day's close and gives `1` if the open is higher (or equal) and `0` otherwise.

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols('^GSPC',src='yahoo',from='1990-01-01')

GSPC$AboveOpen<-(GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"]>=lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.Close"],1))
```

Just in case you also want to deal with single stock data: Keep in mind that `.Close` and `.Open` (at least from Yahoo) are not split and dividend adjusted. `.Adjusted` is the adjusted close.

Comment: thanks @cryo111. Lets suppose I wanted to test for Open in yesterday's range. It looks like the return of 1 or 0 is a part of the lag function. Would the code look something like this? df$OpenInRange <- ((GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"] >= lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.High"]) & GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"] <= lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.Low"]),1)? thanks!

Comment: Actually, in my example above, `GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"]>=lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.Close"],1)` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This gets automatically converted to `1` and `0` when assigning to `GSPC$AboveOpen`. The `lag` function has nothing to do with the comparison (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator) for what the `lag` operation does). To check whether todays open is in yesterday's hi-lo range use `GSPC$OpenInRange<-(GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"]>=lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.Low"],1))&(GSPC[,"GSPC.Open"]<=lag(GSPC[,"GSPC.High"],1))`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @cryo111! Just made things so much simpler & more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df$GreaterThanPreviousClose <- NA

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
df[i,6] <- df[i,2] >= df[i-1,5]
}
```

Maybe this will speed it up

```
compare <- function(i){
 Larger <- df[i,2] >= df[i-1,5]
 return(Larger)
}

df$GreaterThanPreviousClose <- sapply(1:nrow(df),compare)
```

Comment: Thanks @eclark it worked is there any way you could explain is happening with this code? I have an idea but not sure exactly is going on. It appears you created an empty column first then used a for loop referencing the rows using the function nrow & then doing the calculation using the reference notation [i,column_number]. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Sure. 1)First I created an NA column where I'll fill in with the values. 2) Chose a for loop that goes through each one of the rows in the dataframe starting with row number 2. 3) Do a logical expresion asking if row i column 2 is larger than row i - 1 column 5. 4) Store the result of the the logical expresion (either TRUE or FALSE) to row i column 6 . I'm not sure if that is clear. Let me know

Comment: Thanks @eclark! Crystal clear! I have 2 more questions: 1. how can I change the result to be discrete (either a 1 or 2)? 2. this function seems to really take a long time to process. Is that normal? thanks.

Comment: 2) for loops are notoriously slower than vectorized operations so sometimes it can be worth the time writing a function and then applying it using dplyr or plyr package functions. 1) You can change booleans to numeric (0,1) by just doing `df$GreaterThanPreviousClose <- as.numeric(df$GreaterThanPreviousClose)` but if you want other numbers you can always use and ifelse in the loop `df[i,6] <- ifelse(df[i,2] >= df[i-1,5],1,2)`.

Comment: Thanks again @eclark! Hopefully just 1 more question: how can I start at row 1 instead of row 2 in the for loop?

Comment: just change the `for (i in 2:nrow(df))` to `for (i in 1:nrow(df))` but you are gonna run into a problem here because row one will try to compare with the previous row which doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks it is working but I tried the compare are you sure it's i-1 to decrement to the next value in the column (previous day)?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, isn't just `df$GSPC.Open - c(df$GSPC.Close[-1], NA) >= 0` what OP needs here?